# PHP black diamond question marks instead of Cyrillic chars

Tags: php

I saw a lot of answer and none of them solved my problem. It is similar to the others. When i try to take the first letter from this string - `"АВСТРИЯ"`, all i get is this guy - `�`. I tried by putting `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">` in my head section also tried with `charset=utf-8`, with `iconv()`. Can you give me an advice because really don't know what to do with those "questions"? And this is my function if it matters:

```
public function checkForClients($letter){
        $countries = Contry::find()->joinWith('translation')->where(['active' => 1])->all();
        $isSome = false;
        foreach ($countries as $c){
            if(ucfirst(substr($c->title, 0, 1)) == ucfirst($letter)){
                $isSome = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return $isSome;
    }
```

The framework is Yii2.

Comment: When it comes to charsets, you must be sure you are using the same one : 1/ In the database, 2/ With your database connector and 3/ In your html document. What charset are you using in your DB ? And what charset are you using when you establish connection to your DB ?

Comment: utf8_general_ci in the database. How should i check the second one ? When i establish connection. Thank you for the explanation by the way. I realy respect this kind of answer not the copy/paste one.

Comment: I don't work with the Yii framework, but you should find some configuration array in the `main.php` file. You are looking for something like that : `'db' => array( /* ...*/  'charset' => 'utf8', /* ... */  )`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `substr`, use `mb_substr` which takes care of multi-byte safe operations.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php

Comment: What can i say? Thank you million times! Will upvote it as soon as i can!